# Where to find an import statement syntax in Java (Oracle) documentation

Tags: java

Where can I find the `import` statement reference for a Java standard library method in the Oracle documentation?

As a Node.js developer, I'm used to finding import statement references in the NodeJS documentation ([example](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/http.html#http)).

How can I find similar information in the Oracle's Java documentation? For example, I want to use the `Arrays.toString()` method from the class [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and need to know the right import statement to use.

I assume it would be `java.util.Arrays`, as indicated on the top of the page as shown on the image below, is that right?
[image]

Comment: Yes, it would be `import java.util.Arrays`.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.Object is superclass
java.util is package and Arrays is the class name

Basically, any decent IDE suggest available class implementation. Usually, Ctrl + left mouse click on class name will take you to implementation. There you will find identical description to Oracle. In my opinion, Oracle documentation is not very useful.